# Single-field dialog box in Vaadin 7

Tags: modal-dialog, vaadin, vaadin7, confirmation

Does Vaadin 7 provide a simple modal dialog box to prompt the user for a single field of information? Or must I build one myself?

I use this frequently for scenarios such as:

- Asking for a delay of so many minutes before performing some task
- Confirming with a user the name of a report or export to be generated
- Prompting an administrator for a passphrase before a data-deletion task

Comment: You have to build it yourself. There is a dialog add on which does most of the task, but the content of the dialogbox is to be done by you

Comment: @AndréSchild you should write this as answer.